# How to prevent Python from looking into the site packages for a module?

Tags: python-3.x, import, python-import, pythonpath

I wish to do the following: 
from aienvs.Sumo.SumoGymAdapter import SumoGymAdapter
but python goes to the following path and imports it:
/home/azlaan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aienvs/Sumo

I don't want it to import from the sites packages but from this directory:
/home/azlaan/../../aienvs/aienvs/Sumo

I added inside the .bashrc the pythonpath as follows:
export PYTHONPATH="/home/azlaan/PycharmProjects/otherprojects/aienvs:$PYTHONPATH"

There is also another PYTHONPATH defined before this line in the bashrc file, I dont know if it affects it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Python scans the paths present under sys.path list to import the modules.
By default site-packages path will be present under sys.path list and since your module is present under site-packages directory, python will import the module from here.

If you want to import from /home/azlaan/../../aienvs/aienvs/Sumo, insert this path to sys.path list at the 0th index. Add below lines to your script, this should make it work.

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/azlaan/../../aienvs/aienvs/Sumo")
from SumoGymAdapter import SumoGymAdapter